# Using thread-private variables in OpenMP, for __m128i SSE2 variables?

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm, assembly, openmp

Need help in multi-threading one supersimple yet supernifty etude!

It is given below, the commented 9 lines are the generic **Longest Common SubString** loop-in-loop implementation, while the fragment below is the branchless SSE2 counterpart. The etude works just fine as it is, but when trying to multi-thread it (tried several ways) - IT REPORTS randomly correct or incorrect results?!

```
#ifdef KamXMM
printf("Branchless 128bit Assembly struggling ...\n");
for(i=0; i < size_inLINESIXFOUR2; i++){
    XMMclone = _mm_set1_epi8(workK2[i]);
//omp_set_num_threads(4);
#ifdef Commence_OpenMP
//#pragma omp parallel for shared(workK,PADDED32,Matrix_vectorCurr,Matrix_vectorPrev) private(j,ThreadID) // Sometimes reports correctly sometimes NOT?!
#endif 
    for(j=0; j < PADDED32; j+=(32/2)){
        XMMprev = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(Matrix_vectorPrev+(j-1)));
        XMMcurr = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&workK[j]);
        XMMcmp = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(XMMcurr, XMMclone);
        XMMand = _mm_and_si128(XMMprev, XMMcmp);
        XMMsub = _mm_sub_epi8(XMMzero, XMMcmp);
        XMMadd = _mm_add_epi8(XMMand, XMMsub);
        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)(Matrix_vectorCurr+j), XMMadd);
// This doesn't work, sometimes reports 24 sometimes 23, (for Carlos vs Japan):
//ThreadID=omp_get_thread_num();
//if (ThreadID==0) XMMmax0 = _mm_max_epu8(XMMmax0, XMMadd);
//if (ThreadID==1) XMMmax1 = _mm_max_epu8(XMMmax1, XMMadd);
//if (ThreadID==2) XMMmax2 = _mm_max_epu8(XMMmax2, XMMadd);
//if (ThreadID==3) XMMmax3 = _mm_max_epu8(XMMmax3, XMMadd);
{
        XMMmax = _mm_max_epu8(XMMmax, XMMadd);
}
//      if(workK[j] == workK2[i]){
//          if (i==0 || j==0)
//              *(Matrix_vectorCurr+j) = 1;
//          else
//              *(Matrix_vectorCurr+j) = *(Matrix_vectorPrev+(j-1)) + 1;
//      if(max < *(Matrix_vectorCurr+j)) max = *(Matrix_vectorCurr+j);
//      }
//      else
//          *(Matrix_vectorCurr+j) = 0;
    }
//      XMMmax = _mm_max_epu8(XMMmax, XMMmax0);
//      XMMmax = _mm_max_epu8(XMMmax, XMMmax1);
//      XMMmax = _mm_max_epu8(XMMmax, XMMmax2);
//      XMMmax = _mm_max_epu8(XMMmax, XMMmax3);
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)vector, XMMmax); // No need since it was last, yet...
    for(k=0; k < 32/2; k++)
        if ( max < vector[k] ) max = vector[k];
    if (max >= 255) {printf("\nWARNING! LCSS >= 255 found, cannot house it within BYTE long cell! Exit.\n"); exit(13);}
    printf("%s; Done %d%%  \r", Auberge[Melnitchka++], (int)(((double)i*100/size_inLINESIXFOUR2)));
    Melnitchka = Melnitchka & 3; // 0 1 2 3: 00 01 10 11
    Matrix_vectorSWAP=Matrix_vectorCurr;
    Matrix_vectorCurr=Matrix_vectorPrev;
    Matrix_vectorPrev=Matrix_vectorSWAP;
}
#endif
```

My wish is to have it boosted to the extent it reaches for the memory bandwdith, on my laptop with i5-7200u it traverses the rows at 5GB/s, whereas the `memcpy()` is somewhere at 12GB/s.

My comprehension of OpenMP is superficial, I managed to multi-thread (with `#pragma omp sections nowait`) non-vector code, but vectors are problematic, how to tell the compiler that `XMMmax` has to be private?!

Comment: at first glance I cannot find the place in your code where ``XMMmax`` is declared...but maybe you could move it to thread local storage?

Comment: Was eager to post it first, for two days it was a nightmare:
If you wanna play with 'Kamboocha' - the tool using the above fragment, it is downloadable at:


Kamboocha_Intel_(32bit_64bit)_revision_3fix_Single-Threaded.zip 42.3 MB (44,421,896 bytes)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zTxyB8mxCcp1twMEz5KwY8JGjiJMy0Eh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This isn't a [mcve].

Comment: @BitTickler
Hi, no idea what 'thread local storage' is, you are welcome to see the whole tool's source at:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WxUvVqJ53gt5f7WYZzL3uMbyYADzl7Yv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @PeterCordes
Thanks for refashioning the question, it is what I think causes the unstable output, but please note that the question is broader, it is about threading vectors not scalars within for/section pragmas, I found nowhere in documentation such examples - I tried putting those `XMMadd` and rest in private/shared bu no success.
The whole C source code is 137KB (see above).
It is compileable with GCC, only line 57 has to be uncommented:
`#define _WIN32_ENVIRONMENT_`
`//#define _POSIX_ENVIRONMENT_`
The idea is this very fragment to fly...

Comment: Well obviously it's an OpenMP question.  If you were multi-threading manually with pthreads, it would be obvious which variables were local and which were shared, because you'd just have ordinary function calls to functions with local variables.  I don't know OpenMP well enough to answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes Feel free to jump in applying pthreads. Since I use Intel Optimizer on Windows 32/64, OpenMP comes as first choice. I am looking someone knowledgeable to clarify:

- difference between vectors & scalars;

- to point out the correct pragmas in this superb etude;

- to help me in making Kamboocha a general purpose console tool finding LCSS at maximum speed.

My understanding in improving C/ASM etudes is when one says 'a' other fellow coders to come up with the 'b' and thus to boost it further.